# Binding to another control's template

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a control template for a `DataGrid` using another `DataGrid` for row details.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
          RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource RowDetailsTemplate}">
...
```

The `SelectedItem` is bound to the `SelectedThing` property of the control.
The row details template contains something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SubThings}"
          SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedSubThing}">
...
```

I want to bind the `SelectedItem` to another property (`SelectedSubThing`) of the same control. The problem is that `TemplateBinding` won't work here because it's not referring to the same control.

How can I point this binding to the template of the parent `DataGrid`?

Comment: You have double curly braces in the binding `SelectedSubThing}}"`

Comment: Oops! Just a typo. This is not a copy of the real code (too complicated). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `SubThings` is a property of the each item from the `SomeData`? And `SelectedSubThing` is a property of the each item from the `SubThings`?

Comment: Correct. SomeData is a collection of Things. Things is a collection of SubThings. Therefore the main DataGrid's SelectedItem is a Thing and that becomes the DataContext of the row details DataGrid. The SelectedItem of the row details DataGrid is a SubThing.

Comment: @Phil J Pearson - how's about sharing you data template by defining them at a higher level (as a Page's resource for example) and then referencing them at different levels using StaticResource syntax? Just tell if it's too vague and I'll write a quick sample. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

In the second DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SubThings}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedSubThing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
```

RelativeSource allows you to walk up the visual tree, and hence find the mother DataGrid.

Comment: That's binding to the SelectedItem of the parent grid NOT to the TemplatedParent, which is the control I need.

Comment: Have you tried it? you can play around with AncestorLevel also.